# Aspect does not get triggered in the context of listening for a RabbitMQ message

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-amqp, spring-aspects

The `FailedMessageAspect.afterMethod()` below gets called successfully during `RabbitConsumerMain.main()` below. However, it doesn't get called when it's used in the context of listening for a RabbitMQ message - when `MessageHandlerImpl.handleMesasge()` receives a message from a RabbitMQ queue. Any idea why?

**FailedMessageAspect.java**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class FailedMessageAspect {

    @AfterReturning("execution(* com..MessageHandlerImpl.testAspect(..))")
    private void afterMethod() {
        System.out.println("aspect foo");
    }
}
```

**MessageHandlerImpl.java**

```
@Component
public class MessageHandlerImpl implements MessageHandler {

    @Override
    public void testAspect() {
        System.out.println("handler foo");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(String message) {
        // handleMessage is called successfully when message is received
        testAspect();
        // FailedMessageAspect.afterMethod() does not get called
    }
}
```

**RabbitConsumerMain.java**

```
@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class RabbitConsumerMain implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MessageHandler messageHandler;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(RabbitConsumerMain.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        messageHandler.testAspect();
        //FailedMessageSpect.afterMethod() gets called right here
    }
}
```

**ConsumerConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfiguration {
    @Autowired @Lazy
    private MessageHandler messageHandler;

    //other standard AMQP configs

    @Bean
    public MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        container.setQueues(workQueue());
        MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(messageHandler, new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        container.setMessageListener(adapter);
        return container;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't show all your configuration but, just to be clear, Spring AOP does **not** advise internal method calls such as `handleMessage` calling `testAspect()` within the same class instance.

You need to use AspectJ for that; otherwise, all methods you advise must be public methods invoked via bean definitions, so Spring can invoke the method via a proxy. Internal calls within a bean are never advised.

See [the reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) for a complete explanation.